# J2ME thread programming

Tags: multithreading, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am creating a j2me application which is interacting with a database on a server. Therefore I launch a thread to connect to the server. I handle all my command actions in a separate class which implements `CommandListener`.

When I try to get the response the server returned I get an empty String. I have tried waiting for the thread that connects to the server to return but this makes the application unresponsive.

Below is the code I am using.

```
//my network worker class.
public class NetworkConnector implements Runnable {
    //constructor
    public NetworkConnector(String url){
       //url =>server url to connect to.
       Thread thread = new Thread(this);
       thread.start();
    }

    private String serverReply="";
    private String url="

    //method to connect to the server and return the 
    //response from the server.
    public String sendData(String serverUrl) {

      //open streams to connect to the Server.
      httpConn = (HttpConnection)  
      Connector.open(serverUrl,Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
      httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);

      inStream = httpConn.openInputStream();
      int read;
      while ((read = inStream.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) read);
      }

      return sb.toString();
   }


   public String getServerReply() {
     //serverReply is a class variable.
     return serverReply;
   }

   public void run(){
      //call the send method that connects to the server.
       serverResponse = sendData(Url);
   }

} //end of connector class.

// this class is where all my Command Actions are
//implemented. 
public class CommandActionController implements
CommandListener, DataReceiver {

public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable d) {
   //networkMgr => is the worker class that makes
   //connection to the server.
   networkMgr = new NetworkConnector("http://localhost
   /JsonPhp/login.php?uname=" + loginUserInfo.userName +
   "&passwd=" + loginUserInfo.password);

   //here am getting the response from the server.
   String serverResponse = networkMgr.getServerReply();

   //at this point the ServerReponse String is Empty =>
   //yet the server is supposed to return some String.
   System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ServerResponse =" + serverResponse);
   }

   }//end of CommandListener class.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectations about `serverResponse` value are wrong; it can be empty at the moment when you attempt to obtain it in `commandAction` with the code snippet in the question.

In order to get non-empty value, you need to redesign method `NetworkConnector.getServerReply()` to make it properly wait until thread finishes and server response is indeed obtained.

If you do that, however, you will also have to redesign `CommandActionController` to keep user interface responsive - your testing with *"waiting for the thread that connects to the server"* has shown just that.

Redesigned code should just launch the server connect thread and exit the `commandAction` as soon as possible (possibly changing to some "wait screen" to let user see what happens). Next screen update should be triggered only after server response is obtained.

Consider studying a tutorial specifically targeted on explaining how to properly design this kind applications - [Networking, User Experience, and Threads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/threading-155506.html):

> This article explains how your MIDlet can make network connections without compromising your user interface. It includes six iterative examples that illustrate multithreaded networking and the use of a wait screen...

Comment: the link to Networking, User Experience, and Threads =>http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading/ redirects to oracle homepage it seems the article is no longer there. i would kindly request you to send me an article that explains how i could wait on NetworkConnector.getServerReply(); because i have tried on showing an alert screen after calling the connector thread and the problem is not solved yet

Comment: @glapo thanks for catching, link in the answer has been updated

Comment: thanks alot i will study the Networking material to see if i will be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do without java.util.concurrent:

```
Result handleRequest(){
    final String url = // get url
    Work work = new Work(url):
    Thread t = new Thread(work);
    t.start();
    // do other stuff
    if(t.isAlive()){
        // still running
    }
    // this waits until the work is done
    // and it will be safe to access work.result after
    // this call has returned.
    t.join(); 
    return work.result;
}
```

and then

```
class Work implements Runnable{
    final String url;
    Result result;
    public void run(){
        this.result = // do your network stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't start a thread in the constructor. Also, runnable are meant to be passed to threads. The easiest (and the "proper") way of doing this would be as follows:

1. Implement a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable`.
2. Use a `ExecutorService` instead of a `Thread`
3. Use `Future` object to do the processing asynchronously/be responsive to user

Here is a simple example.

```
class Stuff {
    final ExecutorService exec = 
                 Executors.newCachedExecutorService(// please see doc);
    Result process(String url){
        Future<Result> future = exec.submit(new Work(url));
        // do some other stuff
        if(future.isDone()){
            // return result?
        }
        return future.get(); // this call will wait until result is available
    }
}
```

and then

```
class Work implements Callable<Result> {
    final String url;
    Result call() throws Exception {
        // do your network stuff here
        return result;
    }
}
```

See documentation of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit()`, `java.util.concurrent.Future` and `java.util.concurrent.Callable` for details.

Comment: in java ME [tag:midp] API there's neither Callable nor ExecutorService, nor java.util.concurrent. There are no generics, too - it's only a small subset of java 1.3

Comment: @gnat: sorry about that, never worked with Java ME before. Hope the answer above would be of help?

Comment: your other answer makes good sense to me. You'd just add brackets after `join`. And maybe rephrase comment to say like "properly synchronized" instead of "happen-before": thing is, Java Memory Model (JSR 133) has been introduced in Java 5, ie long after Java ME / JDK 1.3 and it may read confusing for developers not familiar with later concepts.

Comment: i appreciate the efforts of all those who contributed to this J2me networking problem. @gnat thanks alot for the networking materials they are simple enough to understand, i have obtained a solution.

Comment: @gnat: Makes sense. Will modify my answer accordingly.